# $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Mod}(R)}(\cdotp,\cdotp) = \mathrm{Hom}_{R}(\cdotp, \cdotp)$

Tags: category-theory

In M. Kashiwara and P. Schapira's book *"Categories and Sheaves"* there's Example 1.2.4 (iv) (its aim is to provide an example of a category):

> Let $R$ be a ring (with $R \in \mathcal{U}$). The category of left $R$-modules
> belonging to $\mathcal{U}$ and $R$-linear maps is denoted Mod($R$). Hence, by definition,
> $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Mod}(R)}(\cdotp,\cdotp) = \mathrm{Hom}_{R}(\cdotp, \cdotp)$.

($\mathcal{U}$ here is a Grothendieck universe).

And I just can't understand the meaning of the last sentence. Am I right that the right-hand side of the equation means that ring $R$ is treated as a preadditive category with one object? But if it is so, the whole equation seems meaningless to me.

Comment: My understanding is that $Hom_R$ is the set of $R$-linear morphisms (supposedly defined before the notion of category) and $Hom_{Mod(R)}$ is the set of morphisms in the category $Mod(R)$. The equality is just that, *by definition* of the category $Mod(R)$, the morphisms in $Mod(R)$ are the $R$-linear ones...

Comment: @Roland Ah, that really makes sense! I'm so stupid. Thanks!